# Not all firebase data messages are received by iOS application in suspended state

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone tell me why application does not receive all data-only messages when it becomes inactive? Sometimes it gets only one whereas another time receives each.

I construct firebase requests as follows

```
{
    "to":"/topics/some_topic",
    "data":{ 
        // some data
    }
    "content_available":true
}
```

Additional information:

Receiving messages in the background ALWAYS works when application is connected to the Xcode debugger